# How to communicate/interface with a forked background process?

Tags: c, linux, process

Sorry if the title doesn't make any sense, it's all I could think to call it.

I'm learning about how processes work in *nix systems (Linux in my case) and I know a little bit but I want to figure out how to do this, if possible, and I can't find anything about probably since I don't know what to call it.

The best way for me to explain this would be to give an example:

Say I have a music player which operates in the terminal, lets call it "musicplayer".
I want to play a sound file, so I would execute this command:

`musicplayer play "/path/to/music.mp3"`

Then this runs in the background and I'm back at my prompt in the terminal, I can just completely exit from the terminal and hear the music in the background etc...

Say halfway through the song I want to pause it:

`musicplayer pause`

Some how the music is paused.

How would this work? (I mean in terms of the process, the music is only an example, the question is not about music).

In my mind this is what's happening: [fork and play music] -> [tell the fork to pause].

I'm not very knowledgeable on the subject of processes yet so any help/explanation of this is highly appreciated.

I don't need code examples necessarily, just logically how this would work but if you wish to give examples you could give them in C.

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: There really doesn't need to be (and isn't) any "fork" involved here (excluding running the process as a daemon); each subsequent invocation of the `musicplayer` executable will start a new *separate* process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand that forked [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) do not share (implicitly) any data; conceptually parent and child processes have each their own [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) and have their own copy of the data (using lazy [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques). See [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Hence, you need to make them explicitly communicate and synchronize with [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s, shared memory [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) with semaphores [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) or whatever other means Linux provides you.

So read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn about the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) available on Linux to do [Inter Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Don't forget to handle syscall failure.

For your `music play` command you would set up IPC and fork (see also [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) to fork a daemon in the background).

For your `music pause` you would communicate with the other process. (you might perhaps consider stopping the process with the `SIGSTOP` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)...)

You need to build in your head an image of all the IPC facilities available to chose the ones relevant for your situation

BTW, several command-line music players exist on Linux as free software. You could study their source code and/or [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) their execution.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all the information (kept reading as you were editing! :D). I think the best thing to do would probably be using sockets for communication.  I'll definitely have a look at the reading material you linked. Thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for relating to the example. This post helps a ton, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add one thing to Basiles answer: this is a very common problem so almost certainly you don't have to handle the details (that can be very complex) yourself. Good application frameworks will provide a solution for you so you can concentrate on making the application great.

As an example, take a look at GLibs [GApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GApplication.html): It handles application uniqueness so the first instance will keep running and any subsequent app invocations will just send a D-Bus message to the original instance and exit. The GApplication object in the original instance will emit a signal that tells your app e.g.that a musicplayer instance was started on command line and and the argument was "pause".